# PHP - Why does the system() method add a header also?

Tags: php, json, system

I was creating a php image upload script. The script sends a post request and (should) have received a json response.

This is the line for checking mime type.

```
$mimetype = system("file -bi -- ".escapeshellarg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])); //line 63
```

and after few line I set the JSON header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //line 124
```

but the js does not works. On checking network tab in chrome:

[image: Error Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function writes all from the shell to script output (something like automatic echo). You can not use header() after some output was sended from script and it happened - system() sended output ("image/png; charset=binary" in network tab before warning).

Try to use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead.

Comment: But if system does not send to html file, and to standard output, why is the html file part affected ?

Comment: PHP script sends automatically headers after first character is written to standard output. system() function behaves like echo and it "echoing" command output that is produced in shell. This is reason why headers are currently sent and you can not use header() anymore. Call header() before system() and warning should disappear.

Comment: According to this doc [http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). It writes not exactly to standard output `php://stdout` but to `php://output`. Everything what script writes to `php://output` is send back to client as a part of response.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't send headers by itself, it is just sending the result of the execution, and once that is sent, it's too late to send headers.

I suggest sending headers first thing or as @kbarborak suggested using exec() function.